# IIS - Unexplained 302 response code

Tags: asp.net, iis

What scenarios cause `IIS` to generate a `302` besides `response.redirect`?  I'm working on an legacy `ASP.NET` app and it's generating `302s` in `IIS`.  The thing is, the code doesn't make any response.redirect calls.  I don't know how to debug this thing.  Could losing `session` generate a `302`?  I'm totally lost.

Comment: Did you check if there's any URL Rewrite configured at the web.config or the IIS app_pool?

Comment: @Fals...I checked the web config and the only URL Rewrite I found is this - Request.ServerVariables["logon_user"].ToString().  I looked in the app_pool, but think I'm looking in the wrong spot.  Will it be under advanced settings?

Comment: What is the target URL of the 302 response? That can tell a lot.

Comment: @LexLi...If you mean the cs-uri-stem, then it's either an .aspx or, half the time, it's "/".  I don't know what "/" refers to.

Answer (score 1):

Check at the IIS level, not ASP.NET level.

Check the IIS management console. Possible options are:

- "URL rewrite module"
- "HTTP redirect" (under the website settings, for IIS7)

Comment: I checked the web config and the only URL Rewrite I found is this - Request.ServerVariables["logon_user"].ToString(). I'm not finding HTTP Redirect in IIS.  Where specifically is it?

Answer (score 1):

It can happen if you return a CSS file in ASP.NET over http when it should be over https, ive seen that happen in the past. Also if any web services tied into that application that are getting hit or making passes that fail, that could cause it too. Just shooting from my hip and trying to recall the last time I seen those issue's arise.

Comment: Do you know how a failed service call will generate a 302?  Doesn't make sense to me. The app is making plenty of these, however.